# R: What is an object of class "Dlist"?

Tags: r, class, oop

I looked at the object returned by `Sys.getenv()` and found that it's of type `character` and class `Dlist`. Its structure is

```
 'Dlist' Named chr [1:94] "C:\\ProgramData" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "ALLUSERSPROFILE" "APPDATA" "asl.log" "ChocolateyInstall" ...
```

There is no function exported by the base package that seems to create such objects.

Answer (score 2):

This clearly demonstrates the extreme flexibility of R's [S3](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) objects.
While I was typing my question, it occurred to me to look at the definition of `Sys.getenv()`. There we find this segment

```
# ...
if (isFALSE(names)) 
  v[sort.list(n)]
else {
  v <- structure(v, names = n)
  structure(class = "Dlist", v[sort.list(n)])
}
# ...
```

where `v` is the vector with the list of environment variables. It can be seen that when the vector is a **named** one, the function arbitrarily constructs it as an S3 object of class `Dlist`.